# Green's theorem find circulation of vector field

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> $4.$ [$10$ Marks] Find the circulation of the vector field $$\vec F(x,y,z) = \langle x^{2018} -233x +y\cos x, 5x +\sin x +e^{2018y -233} \rangle$$ along the circle traced by $\vec r(t) = \langle 3\cos\theta +1, 3\sin\theta -1 \rangle$ from $\theta=0$ to $\theta=2\pi$.

Applying Green's theorem we get
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int_{0}^{?}5rdrd\theta$$

$x^2+y^2=r^2$
$$(3\cos\theta+1)^2+(3\sin\theta+1)^2 =r^2$$
But I end up with $$11 +6\cos\theta-6\sin\theta = r^2$$

Can't solve for $r$. Am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that a circunference of radius $r$ centered in $(x_0,y_0)$ has 
$$r^2= (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2.$$
The parametrized curve $r(t)=(3\cos(t)+1,3\sin(t)-1)$ is a circunference centered in $(1,-1)$. The radius $r$ is then
$$r^2=9\cos^2(t)+9\sin^2(t)=9 \implies r=3.$$